# Get OUT paramater in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUser
(
    IN RoleID INT,
    IN UserEmail VARCHAR(100),
    IN UserPassword VARCHAR(250),
    OUT ID INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO useraccount
(
    RoleID,
    UserEmail,
    UserPassword,
    CreateDate
)
VALUES
(
    RoleID,
    UserEmail,
    UserPassword,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
SET ID = (SELECT UserID FROM useraccount WHERE UserEmail = UserEmail);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

I want to get OUT Parameter `ID` but when i execute this procedure i got the error message "Subquery returns more than 1 row" can you tell me my mistake?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery is wrong here:

```
     SELECT UserID FROM useraccount WHERE UserEmail = UserEmail
```

Here you are compare UserEmail  with itself which is going to be true for every row in the table ith not null values.

I would suggest the better approach will be to change the name of your UserEmail IN parameter(lets say it to email) :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUser
(
    IN RoleID INT,
    IN email VARCHAR(100),
    IN UserPassword VARCHAR(250),
    OUT ID INT
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO useraccount
(
    RoleID,
    UserEmail,
    UserPassword,
    CreateDate
)
VALUES
(
    RoleID,
    email ,
    UserPassword,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
SET ID = (SELECT UserID FROM useraccount WHERE UserEmail = email);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Please try this. Hope you are making sure that 2 useraccounts dont have same email

Comment: i have tried but still error,  "Subquery returns more than 1 row" i've upload the error image

Comment: Are you sure that UserEmail is unique for each row. If not, then definitely you can get multiple user ids for the email..